# How to validate xs:unsignedInt with allow Pattern 0,1 and empty value in xsd?

Tags: validation, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to validate the following element:-

```
 <xs:element name="IsBucketRequired" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
```

Validation required:-

```
  1. Allow 1,0 [Pattern]
  2. Allow Empty value.
```

I try with following code:-

```
    <xs:element name="IsBucketRequired" nillable="true"  minOccurs="1">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
          <xs:pattern value="[1,0]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

Above method validate 1,0 correctly but it's not allow Empty value.

another try for same validation but not working.

```
  <xs:element name="IsBucketRequired">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:union>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:length value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
              <xs:pattern value="[1,0]"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

Anyone please tell me how to write validation code for my requirement.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your first attempt (nillabel="true") should work. You just need to express that element in XML instance is empty (="null") by xsi:nil="true" attribute.

```
<IsBucketRequired xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
```

Alternatively you can define your simple type as a restriction of xs:string.

```
<xs:simpleType name="zeroOrOneOrEmpty">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="" />
        <xs:enumeration value="1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="0" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Third option could be definition using union like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="zeroOrOne">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="0" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="zeroOrOneOrEmpty">
        <xs:union memberTypes="zeroOrOne emptyString" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="IsBucketRequired" type="zeroOrOneOrEmpty" />

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I'm unable to Edit in XML File. I try with your Second option. But it's not working for me.

Comment: You will need to attach sample xml to your question. Otherwise it is impossible to find the problem.